# Sylius DisplayAction Requirements

Tags: symfony, routes, requirements, sylius

i need for Sylius displayAction a requirement like that:

```
foo_display:
    pattern: /{slug}/{stepName}
    defaults: { _controller: sylius.controller.process:displayAction, scenarioAlias: 'foo_ordering', _menu_item: foo_order }
    requirements:
        slug: micropage|standard
```

But this not work for me. It will be exit with the follow exception:

```
The "foo_display" route has some missing mandatory parameters ("slug").
```

500 Internal Server Error - MissingMandatoryParametersException

How i can fix this? I don't want to add the same route for "standard". I will use one for two ;)

Comment: Where are you using this `foo_display` route? Are you referring to this in one of your twig templates for example?

Comment: In my twig template i use:

`{{ path('foo_display', {'slug': 'micropage', 'stepName': context.previousStep.name}) }}`

In Sylius with "sylius.controller.process:forwardAction" it will work...